# Minimize and click on app icon, app should not starts from splash

Tags: android

Step 1: Click on app icon opens up a Splash Screen then comes a Login Screen which has edit text fields.

Step 2: Minimize the app, go to home screen and then click on the app icon.

Expected Result: It should start from where I left.

Actual Result: It is starting from the Splash screen.

Here is Manifest code snippet:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeMain">
```

splash:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeMain">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please paste your Manifest file code.

Comment: whatever you want, by default it will work in that way only.

Comment: Have edited my desc, sorry cant paste the whole manifest.

Comment: You need check every time when app will open that is it first startup of app? if yes then show your one time splash screen else show main activity

You can use shared preference to store data about first startup.

Comment: Culprit is here i guess android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: @pradip_android You don't need to do that. It supposed to work as OP think it should

Comment: @Eselfar yes Exactly

Comment: Is it because you launch your splash as a "singleTask"?

Comment: @Eselfar yes thank you. I got that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by removing `android:launchMode="singleTask"` from our  `manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean pressing the back button to minimize the app, just override the onBackPressed() function and call moveTaskToBack(true). Be sure to remove the "super.onBackPressed()"